# Log Insert and Update Command sql query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to log all Database operations in my webapplication.

I have a LOGS class that writes on Database

```
public partial class LOGS
{
    public static int AddLogs(LOGS log)
    {
        int ret = 0;
        try
        {
            using (var context = new Entities())
            {
                log.Data = DateTime.Now;
                context.LOGS.Add(log);
                ret += context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string w = ex.Message;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public static void WriteDetailed(string query)
    {
        if (u == null || u.LOGLevel == 0)
            return;
        else
        {
            StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
            StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(1);
            if (sf != null)
            {
                MethodBase currentMethodName = sf.GetMethod();
                String metodo = currentMethodName.ReflectedType.FullName + " " + currentMethodName.Name;

                LOGS newLog = new LOGS();
                newLog.Tipo = "Q";
                newLog.TipoLog = metodo;
                newLog.Testo = query;

                AddLogs(newLog);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To log the select operations I the method in this way:

```
 public static List<Agent> GetAgents()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new Entities())
            {
                var entities = (from a in context.Agent
                                select a);
                LOGS.WriteDetailed(entities.ToString());
                return entities.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LOGS.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

but for me it's impossible to log the insert,updates end delete statements

I read that I could use this method

```
context.Database.Log = msg => LOGS.WriteDetailed(msg);
```

and I've tryied to use it in this way:

```
 public static bool AddAgent(Agent newAgent)
    {
        bool ret = true;

        using (var context = new Entities())
        {
            using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    newAgent.DateLM = DateTime.Now;
                    context.Agent.Add(newAgent);

                    context.Database.Log = msg => LOGS.WriteDetailed(msg);
                    ret = ret && context.SaveChanges() > 0;
                    if (ret)
                        dbContextTransaction.Commit();
                    else
                        dbContextTransaction.Rollback();

                    return ret;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LOGS.WriteExceptionLog(ex);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

this works but in a strange way: in a single INSERT operation it will pass in the method WriteDetailed 8 times...

1. INSERT [dbo].[Agent]([Name], [Active], [UserLM], [DateLM])  VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)  SELECT [ID_Agent]  FROM [dbo].[Agent]  WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID_Agent] = scope_identity()
2. (empty)
   3.-- @0: 'a' (Type = AnsiString, Size = 100)
3. -- @1: 'True' (Type = Boolean)
4. -- @2: '1' (Type = Int32)
5. -- @3: '25/08/2017 13:34:16' (Type = DateTime2)
6. -- Executing at 25/08/2017 13:46:17 +02:00
7. -- Completed in 8 ms with result: SqlDataReader

   Isn't possible having the complete INSERT Statement at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gonna need to accumulate lines and detect SQL statement end. E.g. when the line begins with `--` it is obviously past the end of the SQL statement. If you like to capture the comments (and parameters) you can trap the `-- Completed` line. So instead calling `WriteDetailed` directly, you call a method to aggregate and analyze the EF generated SQL text and call `WriteDetailed` yourself as appropriate.

In your `LOGS` class, add the following:

```
private static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public static void SqlLineGenerated(string line)
{
    sb.Append(line);

    if (line.StartsWith("-- Completed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        WriteDetailed(sb.ToString());
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Next, setup logging like this:

```
context.Database.Log = msg => LOGS.SqlLineGenerated(msg);
```

And you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to use more sophisticated mechanisms than just `context.Database.Log` :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx

Apart from mentioned `context.Database.Log` there is also `DatabaseLogFormatter` and `IDbCommandInterceptor`.
Here is an example from the link:

```
public class NLogCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor 
{ 
    private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); 

    public void NonQueryExecuting( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) 
    { 
        LogIfNonAsync(command, interceptionContext); 
    } 

    public void NonQueryExecuted( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) 
    { 
        LogIfError(command, interceptionContext); 
    } 

    public void ReaderExecuting( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) 
    { 
        LogIfNonAsync(command, interceptionContext); 
    } 

    public void ReaderExecuted( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) 
    { 
        LogIfError(command, interceptionContext); 
    } 

    public void ScalarExecuting( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) 
    { 
        LogIfNonAsync(command, interceptionContext); 
    } 

    public void ScalarExecuted( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) 
    { 
        LogIfError(command, interceptionContext); 
    } 

    private void LogIfNonAsync<TResult>( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext) 
    { 
        if (!interceptionContext.IsAsync) 
        { 
            Logger.Warn("Non-async command used: {0}", command.CommandText); 
        } 
    } 

    private void LogIfError<TResult>( 
        DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<TResult> interceptionContext) 
    { 
        if (interceptionContext.Exception != null) 
        { 
            Logger.Error("Command {0} failed with exception {1}", 
                command.CommandText, interceptionContext.Exception); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Easiest way to set this up is by using static method:

```
DbInterception.Add(new NLogCommandInterceptor());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate all lines till you get the `Executing` line, but it wouldn't genetate a plane SQL without parameters.

Alternatively you can try to use `ChangeTracker` to collect data before `SaveChanges` call. You can iterate through results of `context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` and you'll see the state of the object and object data.